# Create User Relations for Parse in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Does anybody know how to create a user relations column in Parse using swift. I want my users to be able to "follow" other users.

Comment: No research? No code attempts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get your user:

```
let myUser;
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
if currentUser != nil {
  myUser = currentUser
} else {
  //Show the signup or login screen
}
```

after get the user that you want to follow

```
var emailUserToFollow = "xx@aa.ss";
var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("email", equalTo:emailUserToFollow)
var userToFollow = query.findObjects();

let relation = userToFollow.relationForKey("followers");
relation.addObject(myUser);
userToFollow.save()
```

I hopefully that this work correctly.